# getting the MVC Views folder path

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have this angular module and want to point at my `Index.cshtml` file as its template like this:

```
angular.module('whatever', [whatever.Provider])
        .config([
            "whateverProvider", function(whateverProvider) {
                whateverProvider
                    .Sample('baseWidget', {
                        title: 'Base Widget',
                        templateUrl: "Views/Home/Index.cshtml", // 404
                        controller: "whateverController",
                    });
            }
        ])
```

And I get this 404 error in my Index page:

```
GET http://myLocalDomain/projectFolder/Views/Home/Index.cshtml 404 (Not Found)
```

So basically the question is how can I get the `Index.cshtml` path?

Comment: Are you able to view the html file on the browser if you point to the URL directly? If not, you may have to update your controller.cs file.

Comment: I am getting the the view at `http://myLocalDomain/projectFolder/Home/Index` but it's the view and Layout. I just want to get that `Index.cshtml` partial path

Comment: Oops, sorry, I meant are you able to see the partial view if you pointed to it directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views folder with all it's content is inaccessible from client and this is due to dedicated `web.config` file inside Views folder that has `BlockViewHandler` handler:

```
 <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

`cshtml` files are not supposed to be used directly from client since they could expose some server-side code which is clearly could be a security issue.

So if you want to sent some template to the client you have 2 options:

1. create a static html file and put in in some dedicated folder (similar to Content folder that you have in default MVC template)
2. Create a Controller that is going to render cshtml files and return them to the the client (this is more expensive way since by default static files are served directly by IIS without involving ASP.NET pipline )